# StringTokenizer problem of tokenizing

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

```
String a ="the STRING TOKENIZER CLASS ALLOWS an APPLICATION to BREAK a STRING into TOKENS.  ";

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(a);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
  System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

Given above codes, the output is following,

```
the
STRING TOKENIZER CLASS
ALLOWS
an
APPLICATION
to
BREAK
a
STRING
into
TOKENS.
```

My only question is why the "STRING TOKENIZER CLASS" has been combined into one token????????

When I try to run this code,

```
System.out.println("STRING TOKENIZER CLASS".contains(" "));
```

It printed funny result,

FALSE

It sound not logical right? I've no idea what went wrong.

I found out the reason, the space was not recognized as valid space by Java somehow. But, I don't know how it turned up to be like that from the front processing up to the code that I've posted.

Guys, I need to highlight that, below code runs first before the above one..

if (!suspectedContentCollector.isEmpty()){
            Iterator  i = suspectedContentCollector.iterator();
            String temp="";
            while (i.hasNext()){ 
                temp+=i.next().toLowerCase()+ " "; 
            }
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(temp);

```
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
            temp=st.nextToken();
            temp=StopWordsRemover.remove(temp);
            analyzedSentence = analyzedSentence.replace(temp,temp.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
```

Hence, once it has been changed to UPPERCASE, something seems to went wrong somewhere and I realized only certain spaces were not recognized. Could it be the reason of retrieving the text from the document?

Following code,

String a ="the STRING TOKENIZER CLASS ALLOWS an APPLICATION to BREAK a STRING into TOKENS.  ";
for (int i : a.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

produced following output,

116 
104 
101 
32 
83 
84 
82 
73 
78 
71 
160 
84 
79 
75 
69 
78 
73 
90 
69 
82 
160 
67 
76 
65 
83 
83 
32 
65 
76 
76 
79 
87 
83 
32 
97 
110 
32 
65 
80 
80 
76 
73 
67 
65 
84 
73 
79 
78 
32 
116 
111 
32 
66 
82 
69 
65 
75 
32 
97 
32 
83 
84 
82 
73 
78 
71 
32 
105 
110 
116 
111 
32 
84 
79 
75 
69 
78 
83 
46 
160 
32

Comment: I'm betting that the original string contains Shift-Space rather than Space (or some other whitespace).

Comment: I don't see issues...it runs fine with me!

Comment: Which java version are you using? On which platform?

Comment: @Enrique: JDK1.6 18
Could it be I have 2 JDKs? JDK1.6 17 and JDK1.6 18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the character codes, the 'space' in question is 0xA0, which is intended to be a non-breaking space. My guess is that it was entered deliberately so that 'STRING TOKENIZER CLASS' is treated as one word.

The solution (if you indeed deem it correct to break up 'STRING TOKENIZER CLASS' into three words) would be to pass add the non-breaking space as delimiter to the StringTokenizer class (resp. the String.split() method). E.g.

```
  new StringTokenizer(string, " \t\n\r\f\240")
```

Answer (score 6):

There -- the answer is in the snippet that you added.  The integers listed show that the space after the word STRING is ASCII character 160, which is `&nbsp;`, instead of character 32, which is the ordinary space.  Edit your original string, replacing the spaces within STRING TOKENIZER CLASS with actual spaces instead of shift-spaces.

Just a side comment, from the 1.4.2 Javadoc:

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that
>   is retained for compatibility reasons
>   although its use is discouraged in new
>   code. It is recommended that anyone
>   seeking this functionality use the
>   split method of `String` or the
>   `java.util.regex` package instead.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you're using something other than normal ascii blanks in "STRING TOKENIZER CLASS"?  Maybe you held down the shift key and got a shifted-space in there instead?

Comment: I was thinking as same as you..

But, the original String was all in lowercase..and I changed some of the words to uppercase..

After changing that part, some of the spaces seems to be undetected which is a very weird case to me..Any idea why??

Comment: Did you change them to uppercase by hitting "caps lock" or by holding down the "shift" key as you typed?  If the latter, Paul's point would seem right.

Answer (score 2):

Do us all a favor and copy and paste the output of this snippet:

```
    for (int i : a.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
```

---

OK, now looking at the output, it confirms what we've all been suspecting: those "spaces" are ASCII 160, the `&nbsp` non-breaking space. It's a different character from the ASCII 32 regular space.

You can let the tokenizer (which is obsolete as others have said) to include ASCII 160 as delimiter, or you can filter it out from the input string if it's not supposed to be there in the first place.

For now, `a = a.replace((char) 160, (char) 32);` before tokenizing is a quick-fix.

Comment: Sorry polygenelubricants,

How to actually replace with the ASCII 160 to ASCII 32 regular space?
because the code pasted by you, a = a.replace(160, 32); didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the cast `(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy/pasted the sentence from a web page or a Word document, chances are you got some special characters instead of spaces (ex: non-breaking spaces, etc.).
Try again by typing the sentence in your Java editor.

Comment: Yeah....If I type it, it has no problem, however, if through some processing only, it has this problem....